# Making sure that only text files can be uploaded using f.file_field in Rails

Tags: ruby, parsing, ruby-on-rails-5, filefield

I have `= f.file_field "file", required: true, class: "filestyle"` in my html.slim in Rails. How do I make sure that only text files with extension `.txt` can be uploaded, but not other files with other extensions like `.png` or `.jpg`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`:accept` parameter of `file_field`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/file_field):

> `:accept` - If set to one or multiple mime-types, the user will be suggested a filter when choosing a file. You still need to set up model validations.

Mime type for text files is `text/plain`. So your field would look like this:

```
= f.file_field "file", required: true, class: "filestyle", accept: "text/plain"
```

Comment: What if I am not using a modal for that, is it still doable?

Comment: @JeffreyYong: I don't see the word "modal" mentioned anywhere in this post or linked docs. So I'm not sure what you meant by that.

Comment: Your solution actually already works for me. The file chooser prevents the user from choosing file type other than text file. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Paperclip](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) or [carrierwave](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) gem.This should make your life easier :)